# How Read a file in GNU-Prolog

Tags: prolog

I have a script to solve a sudoku, but i should read file who is in this format

```
1. 3. 5.
1. 4. 3.
1. 6. 6.
1. 7. 7.
2. 2. 9.
2. 5. 7.
2. 8. 1.
3. 1. 6.
3. 4. 1.
3. 6. 2.
3. 9. 5.
4. 1. 4.
4. 3. 9.
4. 7. 8.
4. 9. 3.
5. 2. 5.
5. 8. 6.
6. 1. 7.
6. 3. 6.
6. 7. 9.
6. 9. 1.
7. 1. 5.
7. 4. 7.
7. 6. 9.
7. 9. 8.
8. 2. 3.
8. 5. 2.
8. 8. 9.
9. 3. 1.
9. 4. 8.
9. 6. 3.
9. 7. 4.
```

my script get in parametre

```
suduko(A1,A2,A3,A4,A5,A6,A7,A8,A9,
B1,B2,B3,B4,B5,B6,B7,B8,B9,
C1,C2,C3,C4,C5,C6,C7,C8,C9,
D1,D2,D3,D4,D5,D6,D7,D8,D9,
E1,E2,E3,E4,E5,E6,E7,E8,E9,
F1,F2,F3,F4,F5,F6,F7,F8,F9,
G1,G2,G3,G4,G5,G6,G7,G8,G9,
H1,H2,H3,H4,H5,H6,H7,H8,H9,
I1,I2,I3,I4,I5,I6,I7,I8,I9)
```

and i should replace some of them by the value in the file, for example here A3= 5, and A4 =3

i don't know how can i read this file and use the variable in my code.

Thanks

Comment: Look up the `read/1` predicate.

Comment: have you read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13615042/reading-a-line-from-a-file-in-gnu-prolog

Comment: Yes but i didn't undrestand how use that in my case

Comment: Please improve your question! It leaves a lot to be desired. Increase your chances of getting good answers!

Comment: it's not clear my question?

Comment: It is rather unusual to read a file with such a format. Instead, one often reads a **single** term that describes the entire situation. In your case, a list of lists would be most natural.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

after saving in a file named 'sudoku.txt' your data, read_file/2 yields the parameters list needed, then, using univ (=..) to join functor (predicate name) and arguments:

```
?- Pred = suduko(
    A1,A2,A3,A4,A5,A6,A7,A8,A9,
    B1,B2,B3,B4,B5,B6,B7,B8,B9,
    C1,C2,C3,C4,C5,C6,C7,C8,C9,
    D1,D2,D3,D4,D5,D6,D7,D8,D9,
    E1,E2,E3,E4,E5,E6,E7,E8,E9,
    F1,F2,F3,F4,F5,F6,F7,F8,F9,
    G1,G2,G3,G4,G5,G6,G7,G8,G9,
    H1,H2,H3,H4,H5,H6,H7,H8,H9,
    I1,I2,I3,I4,I5,I6,I7,I8,I9),
Pred =.. [_|B], read_file('sudoku.txt', B), call(Pred).

read_digit(Stream, Digit) :-
    read(Stream, Digit), integer(Digit), Digit >= 1, Digit =< 9.

read_cell(Stream, Matrix) :-
    read_digit(Stream, RowIx),
    read_digit(Stream, ColIx),
    read_digit(Stream, Val),
    CellIx is (RowIx-1)*9 + ColIx,
    nth1(CellIx, Matrix, Val),
    !, read_cell(Stream, Matrix).
read_cell(_Stream, _Matrix).

read_file(Path, Bindings) :-
    open(Path, read, Stream),
    read_cell(Stream, Bindings),
    close(Stream).

% test
read_file :- read_file('sudoku.txt', B), write(B), nl.
```

Comment: I did what you proposed, i have this error: | ?- read_file.   
uncaught exception: error(syntax_error('sudoku.txt:1 (char:7) } or operator expected'),read/2)

Comment: I tested with latest GnuProlog. Maybe your sudoku.txt is not correct ? Each number must be *immediatly* followed by a dot

Comment: Yes, it was a error in format of file, but now i have this error: yes
| ?- readfile.    
uncaught exception: error(existence_error(procedure,readfile/0),top_level/0)
| ?-

Comment: thanks a lot, it works, last question, why do you put ( .. ) after = in :   Pred =.. [_|B], read_file('sudoku.txt', B), call(Pred).

Comment: It's called univ, a specialized operator. See [=..](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=%28%3D..%29/2)